# Which is better? Redirect from an offline page or provide notification when back online

Tags: intuition, redirect, online-offline

I've created an offline page using Service Workers so that when a user attempts to navigate to a page that is not cached, they will be served the offline page instead.

When on this page if the network connectivity returns, I'm trying to determine which is better UX:

1. Automatically redirect the user to the page they originally requested.
2. Provide a notification of some kind that the connection is available where they can click it or manually refresh to view the originally requested page.

I believe Option 1 is faster and more intuitive since it does not require input from the user. Option 2, however, keeps the user in control.

I know Chrome's "No Connection" page will automatically redirect, but I want some other opinions when it comes to the user remaining in my web app's experience even when disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

I feel the best way is to give him all the information he needs and redirect him with a clear indicator.

So the flow should be, show him the page that is offline and show him clearly that this is an offline page and show a connectivity indicator, that says trying in 10secs with a countdown and a button showing try again.

This way we are taking care of visibility of system status, recognition and giving user control while taking care of the necessary action once it can be taken care of.